# Can iron be magnetized Via electric current in aqueous solution?

Tags: electromagnetism

If you suspend iron particles in water and run an electric current through, the particles gather in a line along the current. Is this a form of magnetism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The class of materials with magnetic particles suspended in a liquid are generally known as [ferrofluids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrofluid) and have wipe application. Buy some off eBay, get a magnet and have some fun.